# window.open does not work in production

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the below code that works fine in development (new window opens as expected) but in production instead of opening a new window it opens a new tab.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".tweet-share").on("click", function(){

    var url = $(this).attr("href");

    window.open(url, "twitter", "width=800, height=300");

  });

});
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: There is no reliable way to force client browsers to open windows as either tabs or separate windows. It's under user control that cannot be usurped. (It *might* do what you want on any particular system, of course, but it might not.)

Comment: i see. is it weird that it works as expected locally but not in production?

Comment: Well that part is a little weird; what browser is involved?  There's no reason that the same JavaScript would be have differently when served from a different place except for things like Internet Explorer "security zones" or whatever they call it.

Comment: i've tried Chrome and Safari. Works fine in development on both

Comment: A few days ago I had a similar problem and inexplicably I fixed it just removing window name. In your case, something like this: `window.open(url, "", "width=800, height=300");`

Comment: I know that It does not make sense, but it worked to me.

Comment: wild, that seems to have fixed it for me too, thanks benjasHu

Comment: Wow that's good to know. (I think my original assertion is still generally true, and you never know what browser developers/designers will come up with.)